# How to start a service with pm2?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pm2, background-service

I have a service which runs in background when I start it.

As an example:

```
pg_ctl -D /some/data start
```

This starts postgres and exits leaving server running in background.
PM2 thinks that the app exits and shows it as `online` for a couple of seconds then `stopped` if I add `autorestart: false`.

So, how can I make PM2 run such a script and make it know that the service is running?

Comment: I can imagine something about script that do polling by pid, but tell me why do you want to use pm2 to start postgre?

It does not sound like a good idea. Postgre works like a charm and if it crashes, it means that something very unusual happens. You should not restart it like "oh, never mind, just restart it dude".

Comment: @ArtemDudkin I think you're right and I should handle postgres just with the tools it has. Excluded it from the pm2 config and actually it works just fine. Thanks!